# NetBeans 6.9.1 and the ruby FastDebugger

Tags: ruby, netbeans

I need to use ruby 1.8.6 to run a legacy script. I've installed NetBeans 6.9.1 and I'm trying to use the fast debugger but when I try to install it I get:

```
/home/eianni/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.6-p420@xml2rpc/gems/rubygems-bundler-0.3.0/lib/rubygems_bundler/regenerate_binstubs_command.rb:34: warning: parenthesize argument(s) for future version
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing ruby-debug-ide:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/home/eianni/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.6-p420/bin/ruby mkrf_conf.rb
/home/eianni/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.6-p420@xml2rpc/gems/rubygems-bundler-0.3.0/lib/rubygems_bundler/regenerate_binstubs_command.rb:34: warning: parenthesize argument(s) for future version


Gem files will remain installed in /home/eianni/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.6-p420/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.4.9 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/eianni/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.6-p420/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.4.9/ext/gem_make.out
```

This is probably because the ruby version is too old, but is there a way to tell Netbeans to use a different version for ruby-debug-ide. I can install withouth problems `ruby-debug-ide 0.10.0`.

I'm using Ubuntu 10.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use `ruby-debug-ide 0.4.9` with `Ruby 1.8.6`, you have to install `ruby-debug-base 0.10.3` and `linecache 0.45`.

To know and manage your gems in Netbeans :

> Tools -> Ruby Gems -> Installed

Comment: Doesn't answer my question. There is no way from there to change WHICH ruby-debug to use. It wants the 0.4.9 and I can't install it on ruby 1.8.6

Comment: Ok your question is not so clear you said "the ruby version is too old" and you ask "is there a way to tell Netbeans to use a different version". So what do you want? Make sure Netbean use the last version of `ruby-debug-ide`? Also have you take a look at this link http://wiki.netbeans.org/RubyDebugging?

Comment: fair enough, I edited the question to reflect that I'm referring to ruby-debug-ide. Yes, I've read it but it's really not about my problem. The debugger is a package used separately from the interpreter and it's installated in the Ruby Platform pane so the 2 things aren't connected imho.

Comment: Ok I found this similar pb : http://forums.netbeans.org/topic27443.html, there is also information is the google group : http://groups.google.com/group/rubyinstaller and here is a solution https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Troubleshooting#wiki-gems_fails_comspec_autorun Hope this last one will help. Also is there something relevant in `gem_make.out`?

Comment: Those are all Windows problems, I'm running on Ubuntu. I've edited the question to add this information. I'll let you know on monday about gem_make.out (ps: I DO NOT have problem installing ruby-debug-ide for my interpreter, the problem is that Netbeans is looking for the 0.4.9 version but I can't run it because I'm using another version, an older one, of ruby.

Comment: In `Tools -> Ruby Gems -> Installed`, what version of `ruby-debug-ide` is present? From here you can install version 0.4.6 in the correct gem home. If you have 0.4.9 in ruby 1.8 you can delete it and install the version 0.4.6

Comment: So I have the ruby IDE I've installed, the ruby-debug-ide 0.10.0. If I try to install the one wanted by NETBEANS I have the error above.

Comment: I think you're speaking of `ruby-debug-base 0.10.0` there is not `ruby-debug-ide 0.10.0`. The last seems to be `0.4.16`. You should install a newer version of `ruby-debug-base`. I've `0.10.3.2` for the `ruby-debug-ide 0.4.6`

Comment: ruby-debug (0.10.0)
ruby-debug-base (0.10.0)
ruby-debug-ide (0.1.10)

Comment: this is my "gem list", so it's 0.1.10 and with my ruby-1.8.6-p420 that's the newest I can install.

Comment: Can you update your `ruby-debug-base` (to 0.10.3.2) then try to install a new `ruby-debug-ide`?

Comment: linecache requires Ruby version >= 1.8.7.
 :(

Comment: What is your version of linecache? Also, have you tried with ruby-debug-base 0.10.3?

Comment: Genius. I've installed the version 0.45 of linecache (compatible with 1.8.6) and now it's working.

Comment: Ok, good! I've change the answer, I gave the version you used to make it works!